# Username and Password in VBS script to be used in VBA

Tags: vba

How can I pull my username and password from a vbs script and input that into my vba code.
I manually input my username and password into the below, however I am worried others may find my login credentials.

VBA code:

```
    Public Property Let jiraUSER(Value As String):          pjiraUSER = "username"
                                                        End Property
Public Property Let jiraPW(Value As String):            pjiraPW = "password"
                                                        End Property
```

VBS:

```
'Input Excel File's Full Path
  ExcelFilePath = "O:\Export.xlsm"

'Input Module/Macro name within the Excel File
  MacroPath = "JIRARestAPIEngine.scriptGO"

'Create an instance of Excel
  Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Do you want this Excel instance to be visible?
  ExcelApp.Visible = True  'or "False"

'Prevent any App Launch Alerts (ie Update External Links)
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open Excel File
  Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)

'Execute Macro Code
  ExcelApp.Run MacroPath

'Save Excel File (if applicable)
  wb.Save
 
'Reset Display Alerts Before Closing
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True

'Close Excel File
  wb.Close

'End instance of Excel
  ExcelApp.Quit

'Leaves an onscreen message!
  MsgBox "Your Automated Task successfully ran at " & TimeValue(Now), vbInformation
```

Thanks.

Comment: Both VBA and VBScript are not safe for such thing. A slightly experienced user can get to them. Create a user form and type them in just before they're required.

Comment: my VBscript is ran via a task scheduler, the vba file will be stored on my local pc, so I think the password wouldn't be accessed by anyone.